How can I align things in a multiline equation (ConTeXt)
I am converting my docs to the new (to me) ConTeXt LMTX.
A code such as
\starttext
    \startformula
        \startalign[n=6,align={right, middle, middle, middle, middle, left}]
            \NC 1   \NC \leqslant \NC  k   \NC \leqslant \NC  n \NR
            \NC n+1 \NC \leqslant \NC  n+k \NC \leqslant \NC  2n \NR
        \stopalign
    \stopformula
\stoptext

which used to work well in Mkiv but the alignment is off (all to the left) in my current version of ConTeXt (2023.05.05, ubuntu 24.04 depot).
I found
this solution on Stack Exchange
which seems to work for two but when I change left for right or middle in the align setting, the output is the same, and it doesn't work for three or more.
Can anybody help me fix this ? Thanks in advance.
PS : I would rather stick to the depot version, because it's hard for me to have the standalone work without dubious hacks.

Not by the computer, so cannot write an answer, but check the new manual: https://www.pragma-ade.com/general/manuals/mathincontext-screen.pdf .

Thank you very much. This doc didn't come in my searches and it updates the syntax. And I discovered some new features too ! Thanks again.

Also not at a computer, but try \startformula a \alignhere= b + c \breakhere d + e \alignhere= f \stopformula.

Thanks to the link provided by mickep, I found that the syntax evolved and the following code works:
\startformula
    \startalign[n=6,align={1:right, 2:middle, 3:middle, 4:middle, 5:middle, 6:left}]
        \NC    1\NC \leqslant\NC  k\NC \leqslant\NC  n\NR
        \NC    n+1\NC \leqslant\NC  n+k\NC \leqslant\NC  2n\NR
    \stopalign
\stopformula

Each "columns" can be aligned by its number.
